# How to compare supplied password equals the user's password in Firebase Admin

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

I want to compare if the supplied password is equal to the `getUser` password

I have try to use [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) but I am not getting what I want..

```
function(username,password) {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(username)
        .then( userRecord => {
            if (userRecord.password == passsword){}
        })
        
    return true ;
}
```

but is not working.

How can I compare even using `bcrypt` when to compare is not working

[image]

also base on the documentation of the hashed password is:

```
 * The user's hashed password (base64-encoded), only if Firebase Auth hashing
     * algorithm (SCRYPT) is used. If a different hashing algorithm had been used
     * when uploading this user, as is typical when migrating from another Auth
     * system, this will be an empty string. If no password is set, this is
     * null. This is only available when the user is obtained from
```

Comment: 1) Why are you doing the password comparison in your code, instead of letting Firebase itself do that? And if you're doing the comparison yourself, why do you store the passwords in Firebase? Why not store them in your own storage, and build a custom provider? --- 2) If comparing the hashes is not working, you're most likely calculating the hash differently than the value stored in Firebase. Can you edit your question to show what you did there?

Comment: I doubt that UserRecord contains the password.

Comment: it has, let me update the question @James

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am writing it as Rest Api, so the admin sdk does not have the option. base on this NO.2 i think it will be okay... let me update the question with the image comparizm

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have update the question with the image, i think with this you will understand what i am trying to archieve

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste [the complete information from the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.userrecord.md#userrecordpasswordhash):

> The user's hashed password (base64-encoded), only if Firebase Auth hashing algorithm (SCRYPT) is used. If a different hashing algorithm had been used when uploading this user, as is typical when migrating from another Auth system, this will be an empty string. If no password is set, this is null. This is only available when the user is obtained from **BaseAuth.listUsers()**.

You're using `admin.auth().getUserByEmail(username)` so you're not receiving the `passwordHash` property. You need to use [List all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) as described in the documentation to retrieve the hash.

Even then [you won't be able to retrieve it without setting up a custom IAM role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#password_hashes_of_listed_users):

> Due to the sensitive nature of password hashes, the Firebase Admin SDK service account does not have the `firebaseauth.configs.getHashConfig` permission by default. You can't add a permission directly to a user/service account, but you can do so indirectly by creating a custom IAM role.